# How to develop a Google Voice app that works with smart devices (Google nest devices) now that Conversational actions will be removed?

Tags: actions-on-google, development-environment, voice, google-assistant

I am currently developing an updated version of a voice app that it was previously developed with [Google Actions console](https://console.actions.google.com/) as a conversational app. However, when started to create a new project for this updated app, a banner says that Conversational apps will be sunsetted on June 13th.

Reading through the documentation, it is not clear to me how to develop now that this options will not be available in the future. Among the options, [App Actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app) and [Dialogflow CX](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow) might be the route for development. However, my app to be developed reqquires integration with smart devices such as Google nest Hub and Google nest mini for interaction.

It seems that App Actions might not be the solution because it adds voice capabilities to an existing Android App, which I am not sure that will work with Smart devices directly.

On the other hand, dialogflow CX looks to be focused on chatbox, i.e. based on text. Again, I am not sure if using Dialogflow CX will be able to provide an appp that uses voice interactions in smart devices.

In addition to these options, I also read about Dialogflow ES, [Cloud-to-Cloud for smart for Google Home](https://developers.home.google.com/cloud-to-cloud/get-started), [Content Actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/content/overview), and [Media Actions](https://developers.google.com/actions/media). It does not look like either of these solutions might be a replacement to Google Actions. For example, I think smart home is not the option because I am not looking to interact with home devices besides google nest hub.

I hope anybody can help and help me understand development path or lead me to information that I might be missing. Thank you